# to print function definitions size along with its name

Tags: regex, perl

I want to print the size of all function definitions.

SAMPLE FILE(real file quite big)

```
....
VideoChainT* ChainCtrlBuildChain(...)
{
   abcd
   edfg
   dfdsh
}
eErrorT ChainCtrlInit(...)
{
   sdgfg
   dsgd
}
....
```

I have extracted function names(There are more also) into a text file using doxygen

function.txt

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain
ChainCtrlInit
```

MY CODE

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(FILE, "< chaincontroller.c") or die $!;
my @lines = <FILE>;
open(FILE1, "< functions.txt") or die $!;
my @lines1 = <FILE1>;

foreach my $func (@lines1){
foreach my $src_line (@lines){
    if ($src_line =~ /$func\([^;]+$/){        # points to function definitions
             #need to extract function body into an array and get its size

 }
}
```

}

OUTPUT REQUIRED

```
function ChainCtrlBuildChain has 3 lines.
function ChainCtrlInit has 2 lines.
```

will appreciate help with this problem or if there is any other way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could fail in many ways depending of your code formatting but you could try with a flip-flop, it is activated in the function definition and deactivated in a closing curly brace. You can count lines while activated and substract three

```
foreach my $func (@lines1){
    chomp $func;
    foreach my $src_line (@lines){
        if (my $flipflop = ($src_line =~ /$func\([^;]+$/ .. $src_line =~ /^}/)){
            ++$lines;
            if ($flipflop =~ /E0$/) {
                printf qq|function %s has %d lines\n|, $func, $lines - 3;
                $lines = 0;
            }   
            next;
        }   

     }   
}
```

In my test it yields:

```
function ChainCtrlBuildChain has 3 lines
function ChainCtrlInit has 2 lines
```

Comment: @Ad-vic: It's because the flip-flop starts at function definition and ends with closing curly brace, but neither the function name nor the curly braces count as lines of the body of the function.

Comment: okay. But you didn't initialize $lines. I think it should be initialized to 0 before foreach loop.

Comment: You could also not iterate through the whole sample file by starting the inner Loop where it left last time. For example using a simple Counter that gets set to the current line number when calling next; and serves as the start for the inner Loop. That is of course assuming that the function names are in the same order in both files.

Comment: no .they are not in same order.doxygen extracted function names in ascending order unlike in code where its random.thats why iterated completly.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(FILE, "< chaincontroller.c") or die $!;
my @source_lines = <FILE>;
open(FILE1, "< functions.txt") or die $!;
chomp( my @functions = <FILE1> );

my $match_function = qr/\b(@{[ join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @functions ]})\([^;]+$/;
my %function_size;
my $function = '';
for my $source_line (@source_lines) {
    if ( $source_line =~ $match_function ) {
        $function = $1;
        $function_size{$function} = 0;
    }
    elsif ( $source_line =~ /^}/ ) {
        $function = '';
    }
    # ignore first {
    elsif ( $function && ( $source_line !~ /^{/ || $function_size{$function} ) ) {
        ++$function_size{$function};
    }
}

for my $function (@functions) {
    if ( exists $function_size{$function} ) {
        print "function $function has $function_size{$function} lines.\n";
    }
    else {
        print "function $function not found.\n";
    }
}
```